# R: Regex error despite it working in regex 101

Tags: r, regex, grepl

this is my first question (i'm still learning R) , i apologize in advance if the question is too stupid.
I'm trying to figure out how to make a regex that catches the first string, but **not** the second one.

> strings <- c("p1_32_XYX_cancer_1", "p1_32_XYX_cancer_ttt_1")

I tested on regex101 and the best that i came up with is this (it works on regex101). However, when i try to input it in R, it comes up with the following error:

> "(^p5[0-9].*XYX.*cancer)(?!.*ttt)"
>   Error in grep(needle, haystack, ...) : 
>   invalid regular expression 'mz|(^p5[0-9].*XYX.*cancer)(?!.*ttt)', reason 'Invalid regexp'

sorry for being unclear earlier, the exact code is :

> ctc_gastric_df <- select(m,matches("mz|(^p5[0-9].*XYX.*cancer)(?!.*ttt)"))

Comment: There is a quote missing in your `strings`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need `perl = TRUE` to make the regex in the OP's code to work without the error

```
grep("(^p5[0-9].*XYX.*cancer)(?!.*ttt)", strings, perl = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks alot, sorry about the post being a duplicate, i searched high and low for an answer but i used the wrong terminology.